# Looping through Numpy Array elements

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is there a more readable way to code a loop in Python that goes through each element of a Numpy array? I have come up with the following code, but it seems cumbersome & not very readable:

```
import numpy as np
arr01 = np.random.randint(1,10,(3,3))
for i in range(0,(np.shape(arr01[0])[0]+1)):
    for j in range(0,(np.shape(arr01[1])[0]+1)):
        print (arr01[i,j])
```

I could make it more explicit such as:

```
import numpy as np
arr01 = np.random.randint(1,10,(3,3))
rows = np.shape(arr01[0])[0]
cols = np.shape(arr01[1])[0]
for i in range(0, (rows + 1)):
    for j in range(0, (cols + 1)):
        print (arr01[i,j])
```

However, that still seems a bit more cumbersome, compared to other languages, i.e. an equivalent code in VBA could read (supposing the array had already been populated):

```
dim i, j as integer
for i = lbound(arr01,1) to ubound(arr01,1)
   for j = lbound(arr01,2) to ubound(arr01,2)
       msgBox arr01(i, j)
   next j
next i
```

Comment: `rows, cols = arr.shape` and just `range(rows)` (no +1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you've skipped over some intro Python chapters.  With a list there are several simple ways of iterating:

```
In [1]: alist = ['a','b','c']                                                   
In [2]: for i in alist: print(i)        # on the list itself                                                
a
b
c
In [3]: len(alist)                                                              
Out[3]: 3
In [4]: for i in range(len(alist)): print(i,alist[i])  # index is ok                 
0 a
1 b
2 c
In [5]: for i,v in enumerate(alist): print(i,v)   # but enumerate is simpler            
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Note the indexes.  `range(3)` is sufficient.  `alist[3]` produces an error.

```
In [6]: arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)                                         
In [7]: arr                                                                     
Out[7]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [8]: for row in arr: 
   ...:     for col in row: 
   ...:         print(row,col) 
   ...:                                                                         
[0 1 2] 0
[0 1 2] 1
[0 1 2] 2
[3 4 5] 3
[3 4 5] 4
[3 4 5] 5
```

The `shape` is a tuple.  The row count is then `arr.shape[0]`, and columns `arr.shape[1]`.  Or you can 'unpack' both at once:

```
In [9]: arr.shape                                                               
Out[9]: (2, 3)
In [10]: n,m = arr.shape                                                        
In [11]: [arr[i,j] for i in range(n) for j in range(m)]                         
Out[11]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But we can get the same flat list of values with `ravel` and optional conversion to list:

```
In [12]: arr.ravel()                                                            
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [13]: arr.ravel().tolist()                                                   
Out[13]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But usually with numpy arrays, you shouldn't be iterating at all.  Learn enough of the `numpy` basics so you can work with the whole array, not elements.

`nditer` can be used, as the other answer shows, to iterate through an array in a flat manner, but there are a number of details about it that could easily confuse a beginner.  There are a couple of intro pages to `nditer`, but they should be read in full.  Usually I discourage its use.

```
In [14]: for i in np.nditer(arr): 
    ...:     print(i, type(i), i.shape) 
    ...:                                                                        
0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ()        # this element is a 0d array, not a scalar integer
1 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ()
2 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ()
...
```

Iterating with `ndenumerate` or on the `tolist` produce different types of elements.  The type may matter if you try to do more than display the value, so be careful.

```
In [15]: list(np.ndenumerate(arr))                                              
Out[15]: [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((0, 2), 2), ((1, 0), 3), ((1, 1), 4), ((1, 2), 5)]
In [16]: for ij, v in np.ndenumerate(arr): 
    ...:     print(ij, v, type(v)) 
    ...:                                                                        
(0, 0) 0 <class 'numpy.int64'>
(0, 1) 1 <class 'numpy.int64'>
...
In [17]: for i, v in enumerate(arr.ravel().tolist()): 
    ...:     print(i, v, type(v)) 
    ...:                                                                        
0 0 <class 'int'>
1 1 <class 'int'>
...
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use the builtin function `nditer`, if you don't need to have the indexes values.

```py
for elem in np.nditer(arr01):
    print(elem)
```

EDIT: If you need indexes (as a tuple for 2D table), then:

```py
for index, elem in np.ndenumerate(arr01):
    print(index, elem)
```

Comment: And if for some reason I do need to work with the index values also? (I know it's not very specific...)